# How to make a Facebook Test Page have an Instagram Business account?

Tags: facebook, instagram

When you're trying to apply for Facebook Permissions for your application, you may encounter some permissions that requires App Review. In my case, I need to use the Facebook Login for Business Accounts, so I need to apply for Facebook's App Review.

In order to make an App Review for Facebook, you will need to provide step-by-steps videos and guides for Facebook testers to test for themselves. However, it does requires a Test User to do this.

A Test User can have a Test Page linked to it, and a Test Page is capable to link an Instagram Account created using this Test User. However, for some reason, I'm not able to convert this created Instagram Account as a Business Instagram Account using the Test User. I tried to link it using my application flow, but the "Convert to Business Profile" button does nothing, and if I try to do this in the Facebook Test Page account, the form that ask for Contact Information always throws a message "An Error Ocurred".

So, I'm unable to create an Instagram Business for testing and also not allowed to provide a real account because they don't allow this, as they explicitly says (Which I can agree with):

> Note: Do not provide your personal Facebook account credentials.

As I'm unable to find a way around this, and I can't see to find any answer on the internet... I wonder if somebody could help with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems it's just a Facebook bug (Just as one I was experiencing before this one, where after updating a Test Account permissions, the permissions were still not working properly) where the Test Account seems to be kind of locked in a state were you can basically do nothing more with it than what you have already done... So I end up creating a new Test Account and doing the same process, but this time it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and to fix it, I had to follow these steps :

1. Create a Facebook test user for your app.
2. Once the user has been created, click the three dots at the right, then edit its password, choose something that you will remember.
3. login as this test user.
4. Edit the user parameters and set its email address as main/default contact address (you need to type in the password of the user). It seems, by default, test user do not have default contact and this is required to login with instagram.
5. Now go to instagram.com, and create a new account using "login with facebook"
6. Fill in the name, password (you need to remember it), and userid.
7. Send the form, and you will get some error telling you to retry later. Ignore it, your account should actually be created.
8. Now **switch to the instagram mobile app** (web interface might not work, I was stuck in a redirect loop) so you can login to instagram using the email address of the facebook test user account (the one you used in point 4) and the IG password (you typed in point 6).

Hope it helps anyone stuck in this hell like I was for 2 days.

Comment: Instagram is requesting a confirmation email, which is impossible because the Facebook test account cannot receive emails; do you have a solution for this?

Comment: This approach works till the point where you get a locked user, that Instagram asks to unlock and asks for the real email and phone to add to try unlocking it. So far no luck unlocking a such account, so it's not clear how exactly to implement testing of an FB app with Instagram.

Comment: I was able to get the confirmation email/text message from IG, but the user seems to be immediately disabled, so there doesn't seem to be a way to actually make an IG business account for testing purposes