# Facebook App Review instagram_basic not being tested properly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, instagram-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

Currently I am trying to get my app approved by Facebook.

My app allows users to connect their instagram account. I use data like *instagram_profile_picture* and *followed_by_count* to complete their profile with reliable data.

For that, I request the permission *instagram_basic* within the Facebook-login process. Obviously the process only works **if a instagram account is connected to the Facebook account** which they are logging in with.

Facebook rejected my app because they could not test the permission properly. But they say that my **screencast** shows a valid use case (where my FB account is connected to a instagram account). I have checked the test-user they have used to review my app and it is **not connected to a instagram account**. What makes requesting the permission pretty useless.

[test-user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9rhO.png)

I thought that Facebook is smart enough to understand that, but I guess that's not the case.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Facebook Test Page have an Instagram Business account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484251/how-to-make-a-facebook-test-page-have-an-instagram-business-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebooks test-user-system is a mess. But you have to try (I tried several times) creating an Instagram-account using **the fb test user**, you should then try to connect the instagram account in **the instagram mobile app** to the fb test user. This worked out for me.